# Coroutine dispatcher confined to a single thread

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is there such thing as as dispatcher which "picks one worker thread from a default pool and does not jump between threads"?

The question is inspired by:

```
    @Test
    fun testDispatchers() = runBlocking {
        val t = Thread.currentThread()

        launch {
            check(Thread.currentThread() == t)
        }

        launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            val tLaunch = Thread.currentThread()

            launch {
                // Note the thread is different, which I don't want
                check(Thread.currentThread() != tLaunch)
            }
        }

        Unit
    }
```

The first `launch` will execute on the parent thread, so it's all good. However, as soon as a coroutine is launched with a default dispatcher, subsequent `launch` without parameters will run on a random worker thread.

How do I make it still run on the same thread?

I suppose I need a dispatcher which would pick one worker thread from the default pool, and keep on that thread with subsequent launches.

```
        launch(newSingleThreadContext(/* pick one from default pool */) {
            val tLaunch = Thread.currentThread()

            launch {
                // This should hold
                check(Thread.currentThread() == tLaunch)
            }
        }
```

I would obviously like to avoid creating a new thread if possible.

Comment: In order to handle Structured Concurrency, Jobs can attach and detach (by suspension point) from a thread and it is hard to find out which thread it was on. And it might happen that when the time this coroutine wants to back on Thread#n then another coroutine might be working on it and Thread#n is busy. You might be creating your own Context through `singleThreadContext()` (deprecated) or `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher` or `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1).asCoroutineDispatcher`.

Comment: You can keep track of https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/261 for further info about backing the singleThreadDispatcher from common pool.

Comment: Yes, that would exactly solve my problem. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Does `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` get a thread from some common pool?